# Add graticule to projected maps in R

Tags: r, maps, raster, projection, gridlines

How can I add a graticule to a the map `ras` below:

```
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(rasterVis)
library(graticule)

## Only needed for downloading a raster example

rr <- getData('alt', country='CAN', mask=TRUE)

## Here is where the graticule routine starts
crs.longlat <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
ras = projectRaster(rr, crs = ('+proj=laea +lat_0=90 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs'))

## Retrieve raster data
#r <- getRaster('temp', day = testDay, frames = 1)

## Here is where the graticule routine starts
prj <- CRS(projection(rr))
extLL <- projectExtent(ras, crs = crs.longlat)
extLL <- raster::extent(-141.1, -52.6, 41.6, 83.2)

lons <- pretty(c(xmin(extLL), xmax(extLL)))
lats <- pretty(c(ymin(extLL), ymax(extLL)))
## optionally, specify the extents of the meridians and parallels
## here we push them out a little on each side
xl <-  range(lons) + c(-0.4, 0.4)
yl <- range(lats) + c(-0.4, 0.4)
## build the lines with our precise locations and ranges
grat <- graticule(lons, lats, proj = prj,
                  xlim = xl, ylim = yl)
## Labels
labs <- graticule_labels(lons, lats,
                         xline = lons[2],
                         yline = lats[2],
                         proj = prj)
labsLon <- labs[labs$islon,]
labsLat <- labs[!labs$islon,]

library(colorRamps)
#brewer.pal(11,'RdYlBu')

col<-colorRampPalette(c("#0000FF", "#1919FF", "#3333FF", "#4C4CFF", 
                        "#6666FF", "#7F7FFF", "#9999FF", "#B2B2FF", "#FFCCCC", "#FFB2B2", "#FF9999", "#FF7F7F", 
                        "#FF6666", "#FF4C4C", "#FF3333", "#FF1A1A"))


## Display the raster
levelplot(ras,margin=F,col.regions=col)+
 ## and the graticule
 layer(sp.lines(grat)) +
 layer(sp.text(coordinates(labsLon),
               txt = parse(text = labsLon$lab),
               adj = c(1.1, -0.25),
               cex = 0.6)) +
 layer(sp.text(coordinates(labsLat),
               txt = parse(text = labsLat$lab),
               adj = c(-0.25, -0.25),
               cex = 0.6))
```

The `sf` package [st_graticule](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sf/versions/0.6-3/topics/st_graticule) provides an excellent example for doing this but is not compatible with `levelplot`.

By borrowing from the above example, I tried @Oscar's code and got this image:

You will see that the graticule does not print and the axes still have the lat and lon from the projection.

How can one possibly print regular `latlon` and `graticule` on this map while keeping the projection of `ras`?

[image]

Comment: You could try package `tmap` which, I believe, can add graticules to raster maps

Comment: @TimSalabim Nice suggestion. Thank you. However, it provides no example for us to follow. I will do some trial and error work with the package.

Comment: There is an example in the FAQ page of rasterVis https://oscarperpinan.github.io/rastervis/FAQ.html#org20515cf

Comment: @OscarPerpiñán I looked at the example. Why do you not label the x and y axes with regular latlon values?

Comment: The raster of the example uses a different coordinate projection system: [see this line](https://gist.github.com/oscarperpinan/5d5bb51ff419621d5f63429b8f88d679#file-graticule-r-L17)

Comment: @OscarPerpiñán I edited my example to include the full code and an explanation of what I intend to reproduce. I tried again and did not succeed. I understand that  `crs.longlat <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")` and that of `ras` is different.